# "Convert to Formulas" throws N/A for values that definitely exist

Tags: excel, excel-formula, cube

I've been building a report in Excel with a good number of cube functions to pull from the Data Model. Recently, a block of cubevalue formulas which had been functioning started showing #N/A. To double check these, I quickly made a pivot table which would pull the same values, and there they were, perfectly fine. I selected "convert to formulas" in the pivot table to see if I had goofed up my own cube functions, but immediately upon conversion, the #N/A values showed up again.

So I know the value exists in the data model, I know a pivot table sourced from the data model will grab it, but when pulled from a cubevalue function, even the one created by the functioning pivot table, I get #N/A.

I'm using Microsoft 365 suite.

Any help would be very appreciated. I'm completely halted on this project until I can solve it. Thanks!

Comment: Please check this link [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question. Thanks

Comment: @DavidLeal - Thank you for the link. I'm sorry to say that I'm unable to create a reproducible example. My model contains confidential data, and creating a new data model doesn't seem to reproduce the issue. I'm aware this is a big ask, I was hoping that perhaps someone had simply run into a similar issue as mine when working with a data model of ~2M rows. Could it just be a memory limitation?

Comment: Have you ever heard of formula auditing? You can find it in the "Formulas" menu item, "Formula auditing", "Evaluate Formula". When opening this, you get a dialogbox where you can evaluate your formula step by step, you can use this for seeing where you get the error exactly.

Answer (score 0):

If there are any errors in the data in "Data model", the cube value formula will result in `#N/A`.